# Using jQuery to render a random font-awesome icon (random string from a list)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm generating a random icon in several places on a webpage. To style these icons, I'm using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) as the list. Looking at that link, you can see each icon is represented by a class styled `<i class="icon-[some-string]"></i>`

The goal is to be able to place code on a page that will then use jQuery to fill [some-string] with an option from that list. So some psuedo example like:

```
<ul class="random-list">
  [for i]
    <li class="list-item"><i class="icon-string"></i></li>
    // Other content
  [end]
</ul>
```

Then I would use jQuery to change string from a list of options. I just don't know how to do this, how to create the array of objects, or how to manipulate the dynamically added items. Since they're adding dynamically like the example above, I suppose I should do the string replace while they are generating instead of doing so after the page is loaded? What would be the process for doing that? I'm using a template that is loading some blocks and I want to include the random icon before each block. Alternatively, if it is easier, I can prepend a random icon before each block, however, since they are dynamically generated by the template, this presents it's own problems.

1) How can I achieve the random icon like I have in the example (template based)
2) Alterternatively, if doing so after the fact is easier, how do I prepend a random icon to each block?

Either answer is fine for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iconArray = new Array(
        "icon-compass",
      "icon-collapse",
      "icon-collapse-top",
      "icon-expand",
      "icon-eur",
      "icon-euro",
      "icon-gbp",
      "icon-usd",
      "icon-dollar",
      "icon-inr",
      "icon-rupee",
      "icon-jpy",
      "icon-yen",
      "icon-cny",
      "icon-renminbi",
      "icon-krw",
      "icon-won",
      "icon-btc",
      "icon-bitcoin",
      "icon-file",
      "icon-file-text",
      "icon-sort-by-alphabet",
      "icon-sort-by-alphabet-alt",
      "icon-sort-by-attributes",
      "icon-sort-by-attributes-alt",
      "icon-sort-by-order",
      "icon-sort-by-order-alt",
      "icon-thumbs-up",
      "icon-thumbs-down",
      "icon-youtube-sign",
      "icon-youtube",
      "icon-xing",
      "icon-xing-sign",
      "icon-youtube-play",
      "icon-dropbox",
      "icon-stackexchange",
      "icon-instagram",
      "icon-flickr",
      "icon-adn",
      "icon-bitbucket",
      "icon-bitbucket-sign",
      "icon-tumblr",
      "icon-tumblr-sign",
      "icon-long-arrow-down",
      "icon-long-arrow-up",
      "icon-long-arrow-left",
      "icon-long-arrow-right",
      "icon-apple",
      "icon-windows",
      "icon-android",
      "icon-linux",
      "icon-dribbble",
      "icon-skype",
      "icon-foursquare",
      "icon-trello",
      "icon-female",
      "icon-male",
      "icon-gittip",
      "icon-sun",
      "icon-moon",
      "icon-archive",
      "icon-bug",
      "icon-vk",
      "icon-weibo",
      "icon-renren",
      "icon-adjust",
      "icon-anchor",
      "icon-archive",
      "icon-asterisk",
      "icon-ban-circle",
      "icon-bar-chart",
      "icon-barcode",
      "icon-beaker",
      "icon-beer",
      "icon-bell",
      "icon-bell-alt",
      "icon-bolt",
      "icon-book",
      "icon-bookmark",
      "icon-bookmark-empty",
      "icon-briefcase",
      "icon-bug",
      "icon-building",
      "icon-bullhorn",
      "icon-bullseye",
      "icon-calendar",
      "icon-calendar-empty",
      "icon-camera",
      "icon-camera-retro",
      "icon-certificate",
      "icon-check",
      "icon-check-empty",
      "icon-check-minus",
      "icon-check-sign",
      "icon-circle",
      "icon-circle-blank",
      "icon-cloud",
      "icon-cloud-download",
      "icon-cloud-upload",
      "icon-code",
      "icon-code-fork",
      "icon-coffee",
      "icon-cog",
      "icon-cogs",
      "icon-collapse",
      "icon-collapse-alt",
      "icon-collapse-top",
      "icon-comment",
      "icon-comment-alt",
      "icon-comments",
      "icon-comments-alt",
      "icon-compass",
      "icon-credit-card",
      "icon-crop",
      "icon-dashboard",
      "icon-desktop",
      "icon-download",
      "icon-download-alt",
      "icon-edit",
      "icon-edit-sign",
      "icon-ellipsis-horizontal",
      "icon-ellipsis-vertical",
      "icon-envelope",
      "icon-envelope-alt",
      "icon-eraser",
      "icon-exchange",
      "icon-exclamation",
      "icon-exclamation-sign",
      "icon-expand",
      "icon-expand-alt",
      "icon-external-link",
      "icon-external-link-sign",
      "icon-eye-close",
      "icon-eye-open",
      "icon-facetime-video",
      "icon-female",
      "icon-fighter-jet",
      "icon-film",
      "icon-filter",
      "icon-fire",
      "icon-fire-extinguisher",
      "icon-flag",
      "icon-flag-alt",
      "icon-flag-checkered",
      "icon-folder-close",
      "icon-folder-close-alt",
      "icon-folder-open",
      "icon-folder-open-alt",
      "icon-food",
      "icon-frown",
      "icon-gamepad",
      "icon-gear",
      "icon-gears",
      "icon-gift",
      "icon-glass",
      "icon-globe",
      "icon-group",
      "icon-hdd",
      "icon-headphones",
      "icon-heart",
      "icon-heart-empty",
      "icon-home",
      "icon-inbox",
      "icon-info",
      "icon-info-sign",
      "icon-key",
      "icon-keyboard",
      "icon-laptop",
      "icon-leaf",
      "icon-legal",
      "icon-lemon",
      "icon-level-down",
      "icon-level-up",
      "icon-lightbulb",
      "icon-location-arrow",
      "icon-lock",
      "icon-magic",
      "icon-magnet",
      "icon-mail-forward",
      "icon-mail-reply",
      "icon-mail-reply-all",
      "icon-male",
      "icon-map-marker",
      "icon-meh",
      "icon-microphone",
      "icon-microphone-off",
      "icon-minus",
      "icon-minus-sign",
      "icon-minus-sign-alt",
      "icon-mobile-phone",
      "icon-money",
      "icon-moon",
      "icon-move",
      "icon-music",
      "icon-off",
      "icon-ok",
      "icon-ok-circle",
      "icon-ok-sign",
      "icon-pencil",
      "icon-phone",
      "icon-phone-sign",
      "icon-picture",
      "icon-plane",
      "icon-plus",
      "icon-plus-sign",
      "icon-plus-sign-alt",
      "icon-power-off",
      "icon-print",
      "icon-pushpin",
      "icon-puzzle-piece",
      "icon-qrcode",
      "icon-question",
      "icon-question-sign",
      "icon-quote-left",
      "icon-quote-right",
      "icon-random",
      "icon-refresh",
      "icon-remove",
      "icon-remove-circle",
      "icon-remove-sign",
      "icon-reorder",
      "icon-reply",
      "icon-reply-all",
      "icon-resize-horizontal",
      "icon-resize-vertical",
      "icon-retweet",
      "icon-road",
      "icon-rocket",
      "icon-rss",
      "icon-rss-sign",
      "icon-screenshot",
      "icon-search",
      "icon-share",
      "icon-share-alt",
      "icon-share-sign",
      "icon-shield",
      "icon-shopping-cart",
      "icon-sign-blank",
      "icon-signal",
      "icon-signin",
      "icon-signout",
      "icon-sitemap",
      "icon-smile",
      "icon-sort",
      "icon-sort-by-alphabet",
      "icon-sort-by-alphabet-alt",
      "icon-sort-by-attributes",
      "icon-sort-by-attributes-alt",
      "icon-sort-by-order",
      "icon-sort-by-order-alt",
      "icon-sort-down",
      "icon-sort-up",
      "icon-spinner",
      "icon-star",
      "icon-star-empty",
      "icon-star-half",
      "icon-star-half-empty",
      "icon-star-half-full",
      "icon-subscript",
      "icon-suitcase",
      "icon-sun",
      "icon-superscript",
      "icon-tablet",
      "icon-tag",
      "icon-tags",
      "icon-tasks",
      "icon-terminal",
      "icon-thumbs-down",
      "icon-thumbs-down-alt",
      "icon-thumbs-up",
      "icon-thumbs-up-alt",
      "icon-ticket",
      "icon-time",
      "icon-tint",
      "icon-trash",
      "icon-trophy",
      "icon-truck",
      "icon-umbrella",
      "icon-unchecked",
      "icon-unlock",
      "icon-unlock-alt",
      "icon-upload",
      "icon-upload-alt",
      "icon-user",
      "icon-volume-down",
      "icon-volume-off",
      "icon-volume-up",
      "icon-warning-sign",
      "icon-wrench",
      "icon-zoom-in",
      "icon-zoom-out",
      "icon-bitcoin",
      "icon-btc",
      "icon-cny",
      "icon-dollar",
      "icon-eur",
      "icon-euro",
      "icon-gbp",
      "icon-inr",
      "icon-jpy",
      "icon-krw",
      "icon-renminbi",
      "icon-rupee",
      "icon-usd",
      "icon-won",
      "icon-yen",
      "icon-align-center",
      "icon-align-justify",
      "icon-align-left",
      "icon-align-right",
      "icon-bold",
      "icon-columns",
      "icon-copy",
      "icon-cut",
      "icon-eraser",
      "icon-file",
      "icon-file-alt",
      "icon-file-text",
      "icon-file-text-alt",
      "icon-font",
      "icon-indent-left",
      "icon-indent-right",
      "icon-italic",
      "icon-link",
      "icon-list",
      "icon-list-alt",
      "icon-list-ol",
      "icon-list-ul",
      "icon-paper-clip",
      "icon-paperclip",
      "icon-paste",
      "icon-repeat",
      "icon-rotate-left",
      "icon-rotate-right",
      "icon-save",
      "icon-strikethrough",
      "icon-table",
      "icon-text-height",
      "icon-text-width",
      "icon-th",
      "icon-th-large",
      "icon-th-list",
      "icon-underline",
      "icon-undo",
      "icon-unlink",
      "icon-angle-down",
      "icon-angle-left",
      "icon-angle-right",
      "icon-angle-up",
      "icon-arrow-down",
      "icon-arrow-left",
      "icon-arrow-right",
      "icon-arrow-up",
      "icon-caret-down",
      "icon-caret-left",
      "icon-caret-right",
      "icon-caret-up",
      "icon-chevron-down",
      "icon-chevron-left",
      "icon-chevron-right",
      "icon-chevron-sign-down",
      "icon-chevron-sign-left",
      "icon-chevron-sign-right",
      "icon-chevron-sign-up",
      "icon-chevron-up",
      "icon-circle-arrow-down",
      "icon-circle-arrow-left",
      "icon-circle-arrow-right",
      "icon-circle-arrow-up",
      "icon-double-angle-down",
      "icon-double-angle-left",
      "icon-double-angle-right",
      "icon-double-angle-up",
      "icon-hand-down",
      "icon-hand-left",
      "icon-hand-right",
      "icon-hand-up",
      "icon-long-arrow-down",
      "icon-long-arrow-left",
      "icon-long-arrow-right",
      "icon-long-arrow-up",
      "icon-backward",
      "icon-eject",
      "icon-fast-backward",
      "icon-fast-forward",
      "icon-forward",
      "icon-fullscreen",
      "icon-pause",
      "icon-play",
      "icon-play-circle",
      "icon-play-sign",
      "icon-resize-full",
      "icon-resize-small",
      "icon-step-backward",
      "icon-step-forward",
      "icon-stop",
      "icon-youtube-play",
      "icon-ambulance",
      "icon-h-sign",
      "icon-hospital",
      "icon-medkit",
      "icon-plus-sign-alt",
      "icon-stethoscope",
      "icon-user-md"
    );
    var randIcon = Math.floor(Math.random()*(iconArray.length));
    $('.icon-front').append("<i class='" + iconArray[randIcon] + "'></i>");
    console.log(randIcon);
});
```

Seems to do the trick, however, getting it to work on dynamic elements will require a delay or something unless I can figure this snippet to run inside the element create template...

Answer (score 0):

update to recent Font Awesome selector labels:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var iconArray = new Array("glass", "music", "search", "envelope-o", "heart", "star", "star-o", "user", "film", "th-large", "th", "th-list", "check", "remove", "close", "times", "search-plus", "search-minus", "power-off", "signal", "gear", "cog", "trash-o", "home", "file-o", "clock-o", "road", "download", "arrow-circle-o-down", "arrow-circle-o-up", "inbox", "play-circle-o", "rotate-right", "repeat", "refresh", "list-alt", "lock", "flag", "headphones", "volume-off", "volume-down", "volume-up", "qrcode", "barcode", "tag", "tags", "book", "bookmark", "print", "camera", "font", "bold", "italic", "text-height", "text-width", "align-left", "align-center", "align-right", "align-justify", "list", "dedent", "outdent", "indent", "video-camera", "photo", "image", "picture-o", "pencil", "map-marker", "adjust", "tint", "edit", "pencil-square-o", "share-square-o", "check-square-o", "arrows", "step-backward", "fast-backward", "backward", "play", "pause", "stop", "forward", "fast-forward", "step-forward", "eject", "chevron-left", "chevron-right", "plus-circle", "minus-circle", "times-circle", "check-circle", "question-circle", "info-circle", "crosshairs", "times-circle-o", "check-circle-o", "ban", "arrow-left", "arrow-right", "arrow-up", "arrow-down", "mail-forward", "share", "expand", "compress", "plus", "minus", "asterisk", "exclamation-circle", "gift", "leaf", "fire", "eye", "eye-slash", "warning", "exclamation-triangle", "plane", "calendar", "random", "comment", "magnet", "chevron-up", "chevron-down", "retweet", "shopping-cart", "folder", "folder-open", "arrows-v", "arrows-h", "bar-chart-o", "bar-chart", "twitter-square", "facebook-square", "camera-retro", "key", "gears", "cogs", "comments", "thumbs-o-up", "thumbs-o-down", "star-half", "heart-o", "sign-out", "linkedin-square", "thumb-tack", "external-link", "sign-in", "trophy", "github-square", "upload", "lemon-o", "phone", "square-o", "bookmark-o", "phone-square", "twitter", "facebook-f", "facebook", "github", "unlock", "credit-card", "rss", "hdd-o", "bullhorn", "bell", "certificate", "hand-o-right", "hand-o-left", "hand-o-up", "hand-o-down", "arrow-circle-left", "arrow-circle-right", "arrow-circle-up", "arrow-circle-down", "globe", "wrench", "tasks", "filter", "briefcase", "arrows-alt", "group", "users", "chain", "link", "cloud", "flask", "cut", "scissors", "copy", "files-o", "paperclip", "save", "floppy-o", "square", "navicon", "reorder", "bars", "list-ul", "list-ol", "strikethrough", "underline", "table", "magic", "truck", "pinterest", "pinterest-square", "google-plus-square", "google-plus", "money", "caret-down", "caret-up", "caret-left", "caret-right", "columns", "unsorted", "sort", "sort-down", "sort-desc", "sort-up", "sort-asc", "envelope", "linkedin", "rotate-left", "undo", "legal", "gavel", "dashboard", "tachometer", "comment-o", "comments-o", "flash", "bolt", "sitemap", "umbrella", "paste", "clipboard", "lightbulb-o", "exchange", "cloud-download", "cloud-upload", "user-md", "stethoscope", "suitcase", "bell-o", "coffee", "cutlery", "file-text-o", "building-o", "hospital-o", "ambulance", "medkit", "fighter-jet", "beer", "h-square", "plus-square", "angle-double-left", "angle-double-right", "angle-double-up", "angle-double-down", "angle-left", "angle-right", "angle-up", "angle-down", "desktop", "laptop", "tablet", "mobile-phone", "mobile", "circle-o", "quote-left", "quote-right", "spinner", "circle", "mail-reply", "reply", "github-alt", "folder-o", "folder-open-o", "smile-o", "frown-o", "meh-o", "gamepad", "keyboard-o", "flag-o", "flag-checkered", "terminal", "code", "mail-reply-all", "reply-all", "star-half-empty", "star-half-full", "star-half-o", "location-arrow", "crop", "code-fork", "unlink", "chain-broken", "question", "info", "exclamation", "superscript", "subscript", "eraser", "puzzle-piece", "microphone", "microphone-slash", "shield", "calendar-o", "fire-extinguisher", "rocket", "maxcdn", "chevron-circle-left", "chevron-circle-right", "chevron-circle-up", "chevron-circle-down", "html5", "css3", "anchor", "unlock-alt", "bullseye", "ellipsis-h", "ellipsis-v", "rss-square", "play-circle", "ticket", "minus-square", "minus-square-o", "level-up", "level-down", "check-square", "pencil-square", "external-link-square", "share-square", "compass", "toggle-down", "caret-square-o-down", "toggle-up", "caret-square-o-up", "toggle-right", "caret-square-o-right", "euro", "eur", "gbp", "dollar", "usd", "rupee", "inr", "cny", "rmb", "yen", "jpy", "ruble", "rouble", "rub", "won", "krw", "bitcoin", "btc", "file", "file-text", "sort-alpha-asc", "sort-alpha-desc", "sort-amount-asc", "sort-amount-desc", "sort-numeric-asc", "sort-numeric-desc", "thumbs-up", "thumbs-down", "youtube-square", "youtube", "xing", "xing-square", "youtube-play", "dropbox", "stack-overflow", "instagram", "flickr", "adn", "bitbucket", "bitbucket-square", "tumblr", "tumblr-square", "long-arrow-down", "long-arrow-up", "long-arrow-left", "long-arrow-right", "apple", "windows", "android", "linux", "dribbble", "skype", "foursquare", "trello", "female", "male", "gittip", "gratipay", "sun-o", "moon-o", "archive", "bug", "vk", "weibo", "renren", "pagelines", "stack-exchange", "arrow-circle-o-right", "arrow-circle-o-left", "toggle-left", "caret-square-o-left", "dot-circle-o", "wheelchair", "vimeo-square", "turkish-lira", "try", "plus-square-o", "space-shuttle", "slack", "envelope-square", "wordpress", "openid", "institution", "bank", "university", "mortar-board", "graduation-cap", "yahoo", "google", "reddit", "reddit-square", "stumbleupon-circle", "stumbleupon", "delicious", "digg", "pied-piper", "pied-piper-alt", "drupal", "joomla", "language", "fax", "building", "child", "paw", "spoon", "cube", "cubes", "behance", "behance-square", "steam", "steam-square", "recycle", "automobile", "car", "cab", "taxi", "tree", "spotify", "deviantart", "soundcloud", "database", "file-pdf-o", "file-word-o", "file-excel-o", "file-powerpoint-o", "file-photo-o", "file-picture-o", "file-image-o", "file-zip-o", "file-archive-o", "file-sound-o", "file-audio-o", "file-movie-o", "file-video-o", "file-code-o", "vine", "codepen", "jsfiddle", "life-bouy", "life-buoy", "life-saver", "support", "life-ring", "circle-o-notch", "ra", "rebel", "ge", "empire", "git-square", "git", "hacker-news", "tencent-weibo", "qq", "wechat", "weixin", "send", "paper-plane", "send-o", "paper-plane-o", "history", "genderless", "circle-thin", "header", "paragraph", "sliders", "share-alt", "share-alt-square", "bomb", "soccer-ball-o", "futbol-o", "tty", "binoculars", "plug", "slideshare", "twitch", "yelp", "newspaper-o", "wifi", "calculator", "paypal", "google-wallet", "cc-visa", "cc-mastercard", "cc-discover", "cc-amex", "cc-paypal", "cc-stripe", "bell-slash", "bell-slash-o", "trash", "copyright", "at", "eyedropper", "paint-brush", "birthday-cake", "area-chart", "pie-chart", "line-chart", "lastfm", "lastfm-square", "toggle-off", "toggle-on", "bicycle", "bus", "ioxhost", "angellist", "cc", "shekel", "sheqel", "ils", "meanpath", "buysellads", "connectdevelop", "dashcube", "forumbee", "leanpub", "sellsy", "shirtsinbulk", "simplybuilt", "skyatlas", "cart-plus", "cart-arrow-down", "diamond", "ship", "user-secret", "motorcycle", "street-view", "heartbeat", "venus", "mars", "mercury", "transgender", "transgender-alt", "venus-double", "mars-double", "venus-mars", "mars-stroke", "mars-stroke-v", "mars-stroke-h", "neuter", "facebook-official", "pinterest-p", "whatsapp", "server", "user-plus", "user-times", "hotel", "bed", "viacoin", "train", "subway", "medium");
    var randIcon = Math.floor(Math.random()*(iconArray.length));
        $('.icon-front').append("");
        console.log(randIcon);
    });
```